# How to solve this error with the interface?

Tags: c#

Visual Studio gives me this error and cannot proceed.
The compiler reports that `IArea` is less accessible as `processingArea`. What can I do?

How do I then enter the parameter in the method `processingArea()`?

I enter into an object that implements the `IArea`, but how do I create an object that implements the interface?

```
public class GeometricShapes
{
    double Area;
    double @base;
    double height;
    public GeometricShapes()
    {

    }

    public void processingArea(IArea poligono)
    {
        var area = poligono.CalculateArea();
        Console.WriteLine(area);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}

public class Quadrato : GeometricShapes, IArea
{
    double @base;
    double height;

    public double CalculateArea()
    {
        Random x = new Random();
        this.@base = x.Next(100);
        this.height = x.Next(100);

        var Area = @base * @base;
        return Area;
    }
}

public class Rettangolo : GeometricShapes, IArea
{
    double @base;
    double height;

    public double CalculateArea()
    {
        Random x = new Random();
        this.@base = x.Next(100);
        this.height = x.Next(100);

        var Area = @base * height;
        return Area;
    }
}

interface IArea
{            
    double CalculateArea();
}
```

I made other errors?

Comment: Try adding `public` in front of the `interface`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order for your interface to correctly work, you should ensure that it is marked `public`.  As for the parameter issue, you should do the following:

```
public interface IArea
{
     double CalculateArea(double length, double width);
}
```

Now when you *implicitly* or *explicitly* implement your interface your declared as *public* and taking the parameters.

Now when you build your object:

```
public static class Rectangle : IArea
{  
     public double CalculateArea(double length, double width)
     {
          // Logic to calculate.
     }
}
```

That would be an implementation.

I modified the answer a bit, so in the `Main` you would do:

```
Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle();
Console.WriteLine(rectangle.CalculateArea(10, 5));
```

That would build your object, then should `return` the area to be written to your console.

Comment: In the Main it is correct to write like that? `void Main(string[] args) { Quadrato q = new Quadrato(); q.CalculateArea(q); }`

Answer (score 1):

Your classes that implement `IArea` are public.  Therefore `IArea` should be public.

```
public interface IArea
{
    double CalculateArea();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

That error means you have a `public` method, that takes a parameter (in this case, an `IArea`) with a more restrictive access modifier. `internal` is the default, so your interface probably needs to be:

```
public interface IArea
{
  ...
}
```

When you think about it, the error makes sense. If you call a public method from another assembly, but can't see the parameter type (because its `internal`), you actually can't call the method! The compiler detects this for you, and throws the error.

Comment: In the Main it is correct to write like that? `codestatic void Main(string[] args)
        {

            Quadrato q = new Quadrato();
            q.CalculateArea(q);

        }`

Comment: @grilletto You generally don't pass an object's instance method the object itself. Thats pretty weird code.

Comment: What would be the best solution?

Comment: @grilletto Its an *instance method* it already has access to the state of its own object. You shouldn't need that parameter at all.

Answer (score 1):

By not specifying a visibility modifier for the interface IArea, C# uses the default of "internal", so it's only visible to other types in the same assembly. However, your shapes are public, so as written, it's possible to refer to the concrete class from a location in code that isn't allowed to know about the interface it inherits from. This isn't kosher.

To fix it, simply change IArea to be a public interface by adding the `public` keyword to the definition.

Answer (score 0):

To resolve your error, you should write : `public interface IArea {...}`.

Indeed, the `public` keyword is used for the classes, but not for the interface, which is internal by default. Or, the `processingArea` method is public, where as IArea is so internal. If you change thus your code, it will works !